# MVC4 External login switches account

Tags: oauth, asp.net-mvc-4, security

Steps to replicate my problem using a MVC4 Internet Template project :

1. Register a local membership account (Account A)
2. Sign out
3. Register a openid account (Im using google) (Account B)
4. Sign out
5. Sign back into account A
6. Navigate to Account/Manage
7. In the external links section click on google

What happens is account A is logged out and account B is signed in. I was hoping for some magic linking Account A to Account B, or perhaps an exception. So It looks like I need to do that part. Heres my code so far. It replaces ExternalLoginCallback in Account Controller.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }

        // Need to do fancy logic in case of multiple accounts

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // check for second blocking account
            // NOTE : This is not a real method, need a real solution
            var second = OAuthWebSecurity.GetUserIdFromProviderUserId(result.ProviderUserId);

            if (second != WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
            {
                // redirect to failure
                // "This Login is used by another account... "
            }
```

As you can see, Im stuck on looking up the account using the Authentication result. Is there any way to look up an account using the provider user id? Any help or insight would be nice.

---

**Hackish Fix**
Ive come up with a quick and dirty fix.

```
   public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }


        // Need to do fancy logic in case of multiple accounts
        bool isBindingAction = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
        {
            if (isBindingAction)
            {
                // tell the user that he has 2 accounts
                return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginSwitch", new {provider = result.Provider});
            }
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just replaced the Login call with a call to:

```
public static string GetUserName(string providerName, string providerUserId);
```

And check if a user name exists for this provider/providerUserId, it would be better.  The only issue with calling Login is I believe that would set the forms auth ticket to the wrong user still.